# A/B test: optimal split ratio for one control and multiple variants

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test

I read in [kohavi et al 2022](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oK2HpKKXeQLX6gQeQpfEaCGZtNr2kR76/view?usp=sharing) on section 7 that when you have multiple treatments in an A/B test, an even split (e.g., if 1 control and 3 treatments, allocate 25% to each) is not the best way to perform the test (to maximize power). Could someone clarify if this is true or if I'm misreading it? My worry is that I misinterpreted the context of this optimal allocation and that it is specifically talking about running multiple experiments while using one control as opposed to one experiment with multiple variants (or is there no difference?)

In addition, the formula for optimal proportion given to Control is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+1}$ where $k$ is the # of treatment variants, and while the derivation is straightforward, the part that I'm confused about is why is it assumed that Control should be bigger? More specifically, the optimal control size is computed by minimizing $\frac{k}{1-x}+\frac{1}{x}$ where $x$ is the size of the control and $k$ is number of treatments, but this formula assumes that control should be bigger to begin with, I don't understand why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read that section carefully you'll see that this is a practice they recommend **against**.

For a pairwise comparison (one variant vs. control) under equal variance you'll always have highest power if the sample size is balanced. Using a larger control sample alongside multiple variants comes with a reference to [Tang *et al*. (2010)](https://research.google/pubs/overlapping-experiment-infrastructure-more-better-faster-experimentation/). The underlying idea seems to be that estimating the variance in the control arm more accurately will benefit *all* comparisons, and making it larger is therefore a more efficient use of sample size than preserving balance in each individual comparison the more that control group is re-used.

Kohavi *et al*. raise several issues with that approach, summarizing some of them:

- Issues like 'cookie churn' (exposure to several variants) and shared resources will disproportionately affect smaller and larger groups in your sample respectively.
- Skewness or lack of equal variances (an important assumption behind this practice) will lead to considerably higher inflation of type I error than in the balanced case.

They conclude:

> We do not
> think this benefit justifies all the potential issues with unequal variants, and therefore recommend against the use of a large (shared) control.